# Firebase functions, counting elements for big data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Recently Firebase introduce [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

In my case this feature is very usefull to count elements in my database.

Firebase posted a [sample code to count elements](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js) but I ask myself some questions with big data.

**In our example we consider that we need to count likes for a post.**

In the sample code, at each new like, the function count all likes for the current post and update the count.

**Do you think it's a good solution for big data ? (For example if we have 1M likes)**

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Likely not. In order to do a count all of the data would have to be loaded into memory. It would be better to use transactions to increment a numerical counter with each individual like and denormalize your data that way.

Comment: It seems like Functions would be okay for this as long as they ran on individual adds? That should be better than loading all the data into memory. Looks like we have an [example of this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count)

Comment: I use firebase in combination with other databases that are more suited for those types of queries.

You can stream your firebase data into Big Query, Algolia, Graph database or SQL database using functions and accomplish more if big data queries are your goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed that the code in the functions sample is not ideal for large sets of data.

For a long time I've used a two-stepped approach in my counters:

1. when a child is added/removed, increase/decrease the counter
2. when the counter gets deleted, recount all the children (as it does now)

So case #2 is memory-bound the same as the current code. But case #1 triggers on child writes, so is a lot less memory hungry.

The code:

```
// Keeps track of the length of the 'likes' child list in a separate property.
exports.countlikechange = functions.database.ref("/posts/{postid}/likes/{likeid}").onWrite((event) => {
  var collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;
  var countRef = collectionRef.parent.child('likes_count');

  return countRef.transaction(function(current) {
    if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
      return (current || 0) + 1;
    }
    else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
      return (current || 0) - 1;
    }
  });
});

// If the number of likes gets deleted, recount the number of likes
exports.recountlikes = functions.database.ref("/posts/{postid}/likes_count").onWrite((event) => {
  if (!event.data.exists()) {
    var counterRef = event.data.ref;
    var collectionRef = counterRef.parent.child('likes');
    return collectionRef.once('value', function(messagesData) {
      return counterRef.set(messagesData.numChildren());
    });
  }
});
```

I also submitted this in a PR for the repo.

Answer (score 1):

See the sample of this in [functions-samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count).

Given a data structure similar to this:

```
/functions-project-12345
    /posts
        /key-123456
            likes_count: 32
            /likes 
                user123456: true
                user456789: true
                user786245: true
                ...
```

This function would do the trick:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Keeps track of the length of the 'likes' child list in a separate attribute.
exports.countlikes = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postid}/likes').onWrite(event => {
  return event.data.ref.parent.child('likes_count').set(event.data.numChildren());
});
```

Note that this code is copyright Google and apache licensed. [See the code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js) for more details.

Comment: This sample code is linked in my question... And my question is "Do you think it's a good solution for big data ?"

Comment: Ah, sorry. I assumed we were talking about technical questions rather than opinions here. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I think it's pretty technical. I'm sorry if I didn't gave enough precision. I know this solution works perfectly but maybe I should use an other solution if I have lot of data. "event.data.numChildren()" can be very high.